# Receiving junk characters when reading from a stream and writing it back to a file

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, fstream, corruption

i have been messing around with raw image headers, things like bitmap headers, icon headers etc just to see how one could use it to wrap custom data inside, but i have one problem, if i read from a stream the vector contains just as many bytes as the file stored on disk, but when i write its contents out to file(even without the ppm header) it contains junk characters, its about 150 bytes longer than what the original file was :L this makes me think that the input stream appends junk character.

Here's my code, StreamReadFile and GetFilesize is just some functions that i need because i do alot of reading and writing to file in my project ^^

```
vector<char> StreamReadFile(LPWSTR path, long FileSize, int pos) {

     ifstream InputStream(path, ios::in | ios::binary);
     vector<char> buffer(FileSize);

     long ticks = 0;

     if(pos > 0) {
         InputStream.seekg(pos);
     }

     while(FileSize > ticks) {
         buffer[ticks] = InputStream.get();
         ticks++;
     }
     return buffer;
}

long GetFileSize(LPWSTR path) {

     ifstream stream(path, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

     if(stream.is_open()) {
         stream.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
         return (long) stream.tellg();
     }

     return -1;
}

int CreatePPM(vector<char> image) {
     #pragma pack(push, 1)

     PPMFILEHEADER ppm;
     ppm.width = image.size() / 2;
     ppm.height = image.size() / 2;
     ppm.size = image.size();
     ppm.data = image.data();

     vector<char> input = StreamReadFile(L"MessageBox.exe", GetFileSize(L"MessageBox.exe"), 0);

     ofstream filestream("drop.ppm");
     filestream.write(input.data(), input.size());
     filestream.close();

     #pragma pack(pop)

     return 0;
}
```

Any help whatsoever will be greatly appreciated ^^

Best regards Paze.

Comment: You're not opening the output file in binary mode.

Comment: ahh thanks that fixed it :P i just forgot to open it in binary mode :L haha thanks anyways